# Is there a built-in way to check if #next or #peek will raise StopIteration?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I'm working with a few iterators where I have to do something along these lines (`enum` is an enumerator)

```rb
enums_with_zero << enum.rewind if enum.peek == 0
```

which normally works fine, but this is after there's already been `#next` called on the enum a few times. The issue with this is that the `enum` could be at the end and with a few values passed for `enum`, I have hit the issue where `enum.peek` raises `StopIteration` because the `enum` is completed. Is there a way I could put in a guard to check if `enum.peek` or `enum.next` will cause `StopIteration` before I call it. Something that would have the behavior of this for example?

```rb
class Enumerator
  def has_next?
    begin
      peek && true
    rescue StopIteration
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `rescue` the `StopIteration` explicitly, but there's also the idea that the `loop` method internally rescues a `StopIteration` exception by simply exiting the loop. (Inside `loop`, `raise StopIteration` has the same effect as `break`.)

This code simply exits the loop when you try to peek past the end:

```
a = %w(a b c d e).to_enum

loop do
  print a.peek
  a.next
end
```

The code outputs `abcde`. (It also transparently raises and rescues `StopIteration`.)

So, if you want to simply ignore the `StopIteration` exception when you try to peek past the end, just use `loop`.

Of course, once you peek past the end, you'll get dumped out of the loop. If you don't want that, you can use `while` and `rescue` to customize behavior. For example, if you want to avoid exiting if you peek past the end, and exit when you iterate past the end using `next`, you could do something like this:

```
a = %w(a b c d e).to_enum

while true
  begin  
    print a.peek
  rescue StopIteration
    print "\nTried to peek past the end of the enum.\nWe're gonna overlook that.\n"
  end
  x = a.next rescue $!
  break if x.class == StopIteration
end

p 'All done!'
```

The last two lines in the loop do the same thing as this, which you could use instead:

```
begin
  a.next
rescue StopIteration
  break
end
```

A point to make is that handling `StopIteration` is Ruby's intended way of dealing with getting to the end of an iterator. Quoting from Matz's book *The Ruby Programming Language*:

> External iterators are quite simple to use: just call `next` each time you want another
>   element. When there are no more elements left, `next` will raise a `StopIteration` exception.
>   This may seem unusual—an exception is raised for an expected termination
>   condition rather than an unexpected and exceptional event. (`StopIteration` is a descendant
>   of `StandardError` and `IndexError`; note that it is one of the only exception
>   classes that does not have the word “error” in its name.) Ruby follows Python in this
>   external iteration technique. By treating loop termination as an exception, it makes
>   your looping logic extremely simple; there is no need to check the return value of
>   `next` for a special end-of-iteration value, and there is no need to call some kind of
>   `next?` predicate before calling `next`.

Comment: A great answer! AND, I'd still prefer a `next?`